# Bash/Linux: Merge rows on match; add last field

Tags: bash

I have a set of wireless stats from various branches in the organization:

```
branchA,171
branchA_guests,1020
branchB,2019
branchB_guests,3409
```

There are 2 entries for each branch: 1st is internal wifi usage, the next is guest usage. I'd like to merge them into a single total as we don't care whether it's guests or staff ...etc.

Desired output should be:

```
branchA,1191
branchB,5428
```

The input file has a header and some markdown so it has to identify a match, not just assume the next line is related --- though the data could be cleaned first, it is my opinion that a match would make this more bulletproof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach: Remove the *_guests* and tally:

```
# file: tally.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}

{
    sub(/_guests/, "", $1)  # Remove _guests 
    stat[$1] += $2          # Tally
}

END {
    for (branch in stat) {
        printf "%s,%d\n", branch, stat[branch]
    }
}
```

## Running the script:

```
awk -f tally.awk data.txt
```

## Notes

- In the `BEGIN` pattern, I set the field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) both to a comma
- Next, for each line, I remove the *_guests* part and tally the count
- Finally, at the end of the file, I print out the counts